# Mvvmcross fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvmcross

I am trying to implement my navigation drawer with MVVMCross but I cannot get the fragments to show. (This is not a problem with the navigation drawer but with fragments and MVVMCross).

This is the code I have in my sample (found on the github of MVVMCross), **see github links below**!

I have one **activity** extending the `MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity<MainViewModel>`, this is the `MainActivity` containing the **`FrameLayout`** (Called `Resource.Id.content_frame`)

I have an **`MvxFragment`** called `FirstFragment`:

```
[MvxFragment(typeof(MainViewModel), Resource.Id.content_frame, true)]
[Register(nameof(FirstFragment))]
public class FirstFragment : MvxFragment<FirstViewModel>
{
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        var view = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.FirstView, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

I also have the following code added in my **`MainViewModel`**:

```
public class MainViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private readonly IMvxNavigationService _navigationService;

    public MainViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
    }

    public override async Task Initialize()
    {
        await _navigationService.Navigate<FirstViewModel>();
    }
}
```

### Github links:

- **My sample is visible on the following [github](https://github.com/kevingoos/NavigationDrawerTest)!**
- And the is the mvvmcross [sample](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/TestProjects/Navigation)!

Comment: Your code doesn't look like the MvvmCross sample for a Navigation Drawer. Try https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/TestProjects/Android-Support/Fragments

Comment: @Martijn00 I found out the underlining problem of my issue I am having, it has something to do with the MvxNavigationService. I posted some more explanation in the awnser below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue => apparently the `MvxNavigationService` doesn't like `MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity` for some reason.

### First Sample (Working)

In the [first sample](https://github.com/kevingoos/NavigationDrawerTest/tree/master/NavDrawerTest) I do **`RegisterAppStart<>` directly on the MainViewModel** which extend from `MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity`. **This is working perfectly**

Some code samples ([for full code see link](https://github.com/kevingoos/NavigationDrawerTest/tree/master/NavDrawerTest))

```
public class App : MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxApplication
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        RegisterAppStart<MainViewModel>();
    }
}
```

MainViewModel : MvxViewModel

```
public MainViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigationService)
{
    _navigationService = navigationService;
    Init();
}

public async void Init()
{
    await _navigationService.Navigate<FirstViewModel>();
}
```

### Second Sample (Issue)

In the [second sample](https://github.com/kevingoos/NavigationDrawerTest/tree/master/NavDrawerTest2) **I first call another activity**(StartActivity) and then go to the `MainActivity`. This gives **problems** because the `MainViewModel` is not **called with** `RegisterAppStart<>` but with the **`IMvxNavigationService.Navigate<MainViewModel>()`**

Some code samples ([for full code see link](https://github.com/kevingoos/NavigationDrawerTest/tree/master/NavDrawerTest2))

```
public class App : MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxApplication
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        RegisterAppStart<StartViewModel>();
    }
}
```

StartViewModel:

```
public class StartViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private readonly IMvxNavigationService _navigationService;

    public ICommand StartCommand => new MvxCommand(ExecuteStart);

    public StartViewModel()
    {
        _navigationService = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxNavigationService>();
    }

    private async void ExecuteStart()
    {
        await _navigationService.Navigate<MainViewModel>();
    }
}
```

Difference:

- First ViewModel: `RegisterAppStart<StartViewModel>();`
- Called from the navigation service: `await _navigationService.Navigate<MainViewModel>();`